# How can I get the column name and value for an ActiveRecord association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I want to get the column name and value. Here is the code I am working with:

```
@products.features.each do |feature|
    puts feature.color
    puts feature.size 
    puts feature.flavor
    # etc....
end
```

I want to loop thru ... something like:

```
@products.features.each do |column, value|
  puts column + ":" + value
end
```

I know I can create a Hash and map them in the controller. But I was wondering if there is a nicer way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#column_names` is a method that gets all of an AR's column names in string form.

`.collect(&:to_sym)` calls `to_sym` on each one of these and puts them in an array.

```
column_names = Feature.column_names.collect(&:to_sym)
@products.features.each do |feature|
  #iterate thru column names. btw string interpolation is better than using +
  column_names.each { |column| puts "#{column} : #{feature.send(column)}" }
end
```

Comment: it doesn't like the 'feature.column' - Undefined method.

Comment: Wouldn't it be #{feature.send(column)}?